# Enable networkmanager after Arch installation

Tags: linux, arch-linux, network-interface, networkmanager

I'm new to arch and am trying to enable the networkmanager.
I'm using a laptop without a ethernet port therefor trying to connect wirlessly. I looked on the wiki and seem to be stuck.

I've just installed arch manually, rebooted and realised I couldn't install any packages.
I used `ping -c 5 8.8.8.8` to check if it was network connection and received **Network is unreachable**.

I've checked the driver status with `lspci -k`
[image: driver status]

I've used `dmesg | grep usbcore`
. When I use `ip link`
, it only has the loopback **lo:**
[image: ip link output]

I've tried `iw dev` but it doesn't recognise the command.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is `iwd` installed. `systemctl start iwd`. You can then use `iwctl` to configure your wifi. You don't really need network-manager. The default networking management for Arch is systemd-networkd. See `man systemd.network`

Comment: @StephenBoston I started the installed process again and made sure iwd was installed this time. It turned out to be not installing firmware and wireless-tools.

Answer (score -1):

It happens sometimes, usually it's because you didn't install any network manager package. In this case, due to it's a fresh installation, the best thing to do, and the best one in my opinion, it's to reinstall Arch and make sure to add a network manager to the pre-install packages before finishing the installation.

Comment: you don't have to reinstall, you can just [chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chroot) then reinstall networkmanager

Comment: @cinemassacres Never say "have to", but it's recommended, that sometimes the base network manager does not work because of several things, it's preferable to redo the installation, it would not consume more than 10 min.